# Stack within ListView fails Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to add a `Stack` within a `ListView` in a `SafeArea`. However, there is a runtime exception as seen below:

```
BoxConstraints forces an infinite height.
I/flutter (18717): These invalid constraints were provided to RenderConstrainedBox's layout() function by the following
I/flutter (18717): function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
I/flutter (18717):   RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:259:13)
I/flutter (18717): The offending constraints were:
I/flutter (18717):   BoxConstraints(w=411.4, h=Infinity)
```

My code:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SizeConfig().init(context);

    return new Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            top: true,
            child: ListView(  shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[_buildFrostedRow(context)])));
  }


  Stack _buildFrostedRow(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints.expand(), child: _showCardRow()),
      new Center(
        child: new ClipRect(
          child: new BackdropFilter(
            filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
            child: new Container(
              width: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 90,
              height: SizeConfig.safeBlockVertical * 20,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.shade200.withOpacity(0.5)),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text('Frosted',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display3),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
  }
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to limit height to **Stack** (put it into Container and set height or something like that). Because if you didn't, the **ListView** cannot calculate layout.

Comment: ohh jeez that worked! If you can add a answer, I will accept it and close this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to limit height to Stack (put it into Container and set height or something like that). Because if you didn't, the ListView cannot calculate layout.

```dart
return new Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            top: true,
            child: ListView(  shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[Container(height:200, // can change
                           child: _buildFrostedRow(context))])));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Stack with Constrained box or Fixed Heigh Container.
Because, Listview and Stack has infinite height